# How can I encourage my neural net classifier to make fewer confident, but wrong, decisions?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a classification problem where I want to be able to rely on the probability estimates from my classifier. I'm using softmax at the output with categorical crossentropy loss function. While the classification accuracy is good, I have a significant number of misclassification cases where the correct answer has approximately zero probability at the output.  In other words, the network is very confident and wrong.

Note that for this application, I have the ability to generate good training data from simulation.  I train without ever repeating training data, so I'm not concerned with overfitting.

What approaches, methods, or tricks are available to get my network to be less confident?  It's more important to have *some* probability on correct answers all the time than to have correct answers drive all the way to 1.0 most of the time, if that makes sense. At the same time, just flattening the PMF after the fact is not really helpful.

Comment: "the network is very confident and wrong" - on training data or test data? Label smoothing during training could be helpful.

Comment: Overconfident on test data.  I use no data twice anyway since it's all simulated.  Thanks for the lead on label smoothing.